# Best Known Method for naming namespaces in C++ // what to do when names collide?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, libraries

OK, so I know that I should embed my code in namespaces to handle name collisions.
E.g.

My-Header-Only-Library.hpp

```
    namespace AG {
    namespace My_Header_Only_Library {

    class Foo {
        ...
    };

    }
    }
```

So I have AG::My_Header_Only_Library::Foo.

Yes, I often use two levels - the first, variously AG, AFG, libAG, etc. - for "my" stuff (I have maintained some of these libraries for decades, e.g. `Valid<T>`).

And I often have sub-namespaces for various modules.

PROBLEM #1: namespace names sometimes collide.

Yes: I have found collisions for all of the namespace names AG, AFG, libAG.  Yes, I have run into companies that have the same initials as me.

(For a while I used GLEW, thinking that this is a fairly unique last name. Back then I was the only Glew on the internet, and only the 48th person with the initials AG on ARPAnet. (AG48).  But since then, OpenGL Extensions Wrangler has pretty much taken that away from me.)

I suppose that "namespace AG_some_random_stuff_675567" is less likely to collide.   Is that what people do?  Use some long namespace name, and then a

```
using AG_lib = AG_some_random_stuff_675567
```

Or do you ever try to play tricks like  #defining the name of the namespace to something else.

E.g.

```
#define AG something_more_unique
```

PROBLEM #2:  I sometimes give, loan, allow companies to use my libraries.  Bit I ask that they give changes back, i.e. that they do not fork.

Their coding conventions may not be the same.

I don't want them to change the namespace names, because that makes pulling their changes back harder.

Q: What to do?  Have them do

```
using Their_Name = AG_some_random_stuff_675567
```

Comment: what's next?  naming namespace naming conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start with something about what the namespace contains, my full name, and the creation date -- in theory this isn't 100% immune to collisions either, but it's pretty close<sup>1</sup>. If you really want something a lot closer to immune, you can generate a GUID and use that instead.

Then, of course yes, there's a much shorter alias for *most* normal use. Unfortunately, you can't *always* use an alias in place of the full namespace name, but such is life.

---

1. At least for me it's pretty close -- a more common name would provide a lot less protection though.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as the best, although I think my personal BKM will be a hybrid of this and the Java -style approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're on damage control mode. The company who received your library in a state that collided with their internal names will need to revise their client code to disambiguate the collided libraries.

`AG_some_random_stuff_675567` is clearly overkill and `AG` is clearly (maybe just in retrospect) too likely to collide. Pick something reasonably unique, so future clients can use it without a `using` alias. For example `all_good`. (Although, if requiring clients to add their own `using` alias won't cause marketing or support issues, a namespace with `random_stuff` would be completely safe.)

Then, you can add `using namespace AG = all_good;` inside your own code, and direct older clients to do the same as a means of backward compatibility.

Perhaps use preprocessor flags to help migrate clients by selecting who gets `using` directives in the global namespace, but no way you should use preprocessor macros to rename namespaces! And with a name like `AG` that's already proven to collide.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use initials, use a namespace that's already allocated.  For example, the Java practice of reversing your fully-qualified-domain-name works quite well.  With my code I can safely use

```
namespace com {
    namespace benvoigt {
    }
}
```

and know it will not conflict with an external entity, since it's impossible for anyone else to have ownership of the domain `benvoigt.com`.

Comment: What does `com` accomplish? A name that may collide is useless. C++ is not Java.

Comment: Hmm... ca::glew ...  I wonder if anybody at the company "Computer Associates" works with the Open GL Extensions Wrangler.

Comment: @BenVoigt Java specifies that namespaces correspond to domains. C++ doesn't. Canada and Computer Associates are both pretty big. `com` can mean "common" or Microsoft Common Object Model. If someone does `using namespace com;` because that's where they put *their* common libraries, then you're back at square one.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Even in Java, it's convention rather than a requirement.  And nothing will solve the problem of intentional collisions.  If you want, put everything using this convention inside yet another namespace, such as `fqdn`.

Comment: Also, **Component** Object Model.

Comment: @BenVoigt [Google code search](https://code.google.com/query/#q=%22using%20namespace%20com;%22) turns up a one instance of `using namespace com;` and a few more of `using namespace Com;`. The solution is to use a long name at global scope, not to break it up. Whatever the difference between rule and convention or accident and purpose, in Java you would never do `import com.*;`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: namespace com::benvoigt would only be in trubke because of a conflict with namespace com (for component, or common, or whatever) if sub-namespace com::benvoigt were also in use.  Since at the moment C++ namespaces are open, with no access control.  Of course, some of us are waiting for C++ namesaces to actually be closable, as in "nobody else can add stuff to this namesapce now"...

Comment: @KrazyGlew The upshot is, using `com_benvoigt` would get the best of both worlds. Replacing the underscore with the scope operator is only a losing proposition.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I think that is an improvement on average, however `_` is a legal letter in hostnames, so it isn't 100% better.

Comment: @BenVoigt: heck, I have dashes in one of my domain names, so it isn't a legal C/C++ identifier. Soon, there will be hostnames and domainnames with all sorts of characters in them, like Chinese.

Comment: @Krazy: Unusual characters are legal in identifiers (system-dependent).  hyphen isn't of course, so you need to map it to some legal character and that creates a possible collision.